# Three20 : How can I set a URL in TTImageView so that it opens a new ViewController when clicked?

Tags: iphone, url, navigation, three20

I am building an app using Three20 and I would like to have some images I display be clickable and open a new view (for example, a user's profile when you click on a user's avatar).
I already implemented URL navigation through TTNavigator and it works great, so all I need is a way to associate a URL to a TTImageView, or any other way I could achieve that goal.

I browsed through the API but the TTImageView doesn't seem to have any attributes dedicated to that (just one for the url of the image to be displayed). I then thought I could find an example in the TTCatalog sample project but it doesn't show that feature.

Any ideas ?

NOTE : I'm trying to achieve this for images nested in table view cells

Thanks

PB

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is kind of an old question but maybe this will help someone else as well so here it goes: I think your best bet for this is to create an empty custom UIButton that overlays the image.  You'll have to create a subclass of the TTTableitemcell you are using to do this if you haven't already.